# Why Haskell list comprehension is faster than loop

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell noob. And while experimenting with loops and list comprehensions I have discovered that list comprehension is faster than a loop. Lisp comprehension uses exponentiation and is still faster. Why?

```
lg :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
lg s e a =
  if s < e
  then
  if even s
  then
    lg (s+1) e (a+1)
  else
    lg (s+1) e (a*2)
  else
    a

loopGrowth :: Int -> Int
loopGrowth x = lg 0 x 0

calcGrowth :: Int -> Int
calcGrowth y =
  last (take (y+1) (tail (join [ [2 ^ x - 2 ,2 ^ x - 1] | x <- [1..50] ])))
```

Comment: In general for performance-related questions (as [said in the Haskell tag FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info)!), please make sure you've actually used meaningful test cases, and considered optimisation options. You should tell us exactly what you've tested, and what timings you got. Your two approaches are so different (they do not even give the same results!) that I find it hard to understand how you even tried to compare them.

Comment: @leftaroundabout There's an off-by-one error, but otherwise they give the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First some style advice:

```
lg s e a
  | s >= e     = a
  | even s     = lg (s+1) e (a+1)
  | otherwise  = lg (s+1) e (a*2)
```

Regarding your question: `lg` is not really a loop. It's a tail-recursive function, but that alone doesn't say much in Haskell. The main thing that gets in the way is lazyness: if the accumulators are only accumulated in the thunk-dimension, rather than their values, lazyness merely builds up an enourmous amount of overhead without any usability gain.

A simple way to prevent this is to evaluate arguments strictly, with

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns     #-}

lg' s e !a
  | s >= e     = a
  | even s     = lg' (s+1) e (a+1)
  | otherwise  = lg' (s+1) e (a*2)
```

However, because of such issues but also because of conciseness/modularity/..., it is rather preferred not to write tail-recursive functions at all but use higher level-tools – list comprehensions themselves are often *not* that great performance-wise, but if you express your algorithms in terms of generic folds etc. you can utilise much more performant data structures such as unboxed vectors with little changes to your code.

Comment: If you compile with `-O2` and use the type signature indicated by the OP, GHC figures out the strictness on its own. I think Ørjan Johansen got this one.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the more complicated thunk issues @leftaroundabout mentions, I can think of two *algorithmic* reasons why the list comprehension could be more efficient than you think:

- Because of laziness, only *one* of the list elements is actually evaluated. So only one exponentiation is performed.
- Haskell's `^` is more clever than simply multiplying in a loop: It uses division by 2 internally to greatly reduce the number of multiplications needed. E.g. `x^8` becomes "essentially" `let x2 = x*x; x4 = x2*x2 in x4*x4`. (EDIT: As @dfeuer points out, this is known as "fast exponentiation" or "exponentiation by squaring".)

Comment: You might want to mention that the algorithm is called "fast exponentiation", or "exponentiation by squaring".

Comment: +1, this does indeed much better adress the specific code the OP posted than my answer. — — — — — — — — — — — Oh, right, I still can't start comments with "+1", but wasn't it possible to disable this by adding enough text? Hm, I think I read that in [this post on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283874/remove-the-limitation-that-stops-comments-from-starting-with-1-or-1/283953#283953)... oh my, it's such a useless restriction... (Sorry for the spam.)